# An intermediate Arithmetic exercise

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic

> Deduce that if $p$ is a prime number of the form $(4k + 1)$ for $(k ∈N),$ 
>  then there exists $a ∈ N$ such that $(a² + 1)$ is a multiple of $p$.

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange! Please include some information about what you've tried to do so far, so that you can be given relevant hints/explanation. Otherwise you may not receive an answer as you'd wish, and your post will be downvoted.

Comment: Could you add the link to the source of your question, e.g the book, the page and number of the task? Everybody will benefit from that including you and your question will be SEO friendlier.

Comment: YES I CAN BUT IF YOU CAN UNDERSTAND FRENCH

Comment: If this book doesn't have an English version, then include French version in the body of your question. I include links to Russian-language sources.

Comment: YEAH, GREAT IDEA THANK YOU I WILL DO IT NOW. BY THE WAY, IF YOU HAVE ANY IDEA FOR SOLVE THIS EXERCISE SHARE IT WHIT US . THANK YOU ANOTHER TIME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the product 
$$ 1 \times 2 \times \ldots \frac{(p-1)}{2}\frac{(p+1)}{2} \times \ldots \times (p-1)$$

Notice that $$ \frac{(p+1)}{2} \cong -\frac{(p-1)}{2}  \pmod p, $$ and so on.

On one hand, this product equals $ (p-1)!$ which is $-1 \pmod p$, while on the other hand, it equals $$[\frac{p-1}{2}!]^2.$$ So you have a $x$  such that $x^2 +1 $ is divisible by $p$.

Comment: thank you for your time

Comment: Please accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: I'm new here I don't know how ? can you teach me?

Comment: You'll see a tick sign just to the left of starting of the answer, click on that.

Comment: thank you very much.